# ReadProcessMemory() fails due to PAGE_NOACCESS flag(?)

Tags: c++, c++builder, readprocessmemory

I'm trying to read an integer value from a foreign process with the C++ code below (using C++Builder as IDE).

Both applications are 64-bit, but the [ReadProcessMemory()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) function fails with error 299 ([ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-#error_partial_copy)). If I compile a second test application and try to read a value from it, it works fine. But I can't read the memory from the foreign process. I noticed that the memory area in the foreign process seems to be protected with the `PAGE_NOACCESS` flag. I tried to overwrite it with [VirtualProtectEx()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotectex) but it doesn't change the flag and I still can't read the memory. Is my code wrong?

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    DWORD procid;
    HANDLE hproc;
    long long addrPosX = 0x7FF62C66DA20;
    int iBuffer = 0;
    UInt64 rw = 0;
    unsigned long oldProtect;

    procid = 992;

    try
    {
      hproc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE, FALSE, procid);
      //VirtualProtectEx(hproc, (LPVOID)addrPosX, sizeof(iBuffer), PAGE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);

      // Read value
      if (ReadProcessMemory(hproc, (LPCVOID)addrPosX, &iBuffer, sizeof(iBuffer), &rw)) {
        lblPosX->Text = "Value: " + String(iBuffer);
      } else {
        lblPosX->Text = "Value: Failed reading memory (" + String(GetLastError()) + ")";
      }

      //VirtualProtectEx(hproc, (LPVOID)addrPosX, sizeof(iBuffer), oldProtect, &oldProtect);
      CloseHandle(hproc);
    }
    catch (Exception &e)
    {
      ShowMessage("Error OpenProcess(): " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: `I tried to overwrite it with VirtualProtectEx() but it doesn't` - because you didn't open the process [with `PROCESS_VM_OPERATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotectex#parameters)?

Comment: How do you know that 0x7FF62C66DA20 is the right address in the other process?

Comment: I tried it with PROCESS_VM_OPERATION too, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @NateEldredge It's a value with a fixed memory location. I tried to access it with another tool to ensure it is accessible and has the correct value.

Comment: @StanE Is `0x7FF62C66DA20` an absolute memory address, or is it an offset from the foreign process's base address? If it is an absolute address, change it into an offset, and then retrieve the process's actual base address at runtime and add the offset to it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh, yes... It is an absolute address. My fault, sorry! I'm trying to find out how to find out the base address of the foreign process. Could you write a response with additional example code so I can mark it as accepted answer, please? Meanwhile I'll try to find out how to do it myself. Thanks! <3

Comment: @StanE use `EnumProcessModules/Ex()` and `GetModuleBaseName()` to find the process's main EXE module, then use `GetModuleInformation()` to get that module's base address.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you very much! It works now and I learned a lot of new things.